# C++ cant figure out whats wrong with my function call

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a selection sort, but for some reason every-time i run my code my compiler is giving me the error invalid conversion from int to int. here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

selectionSort (int[], int);

int main()
{
   fstream theFile("test.txt");
   const int ARRAY_SIZE = 12; // Array size
   int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];
   int counter = 0;
   int linecount = 0;         // Loop counter variable
   int finalArray;

   while (counter < ARRAY_SIZE && theFile >> numbers[counter])
   {

       counter++;
   }

   theFile.close();
   // Display the numbers read:
   cout << "The array entered by user: ";
   for (counter = 0; counter < ARRAY_SIZE; counter++)
   {
       finalArray = numbers[counter];
       cout << finalArray << " ";
   }

  selectionSort(finalArray, ARRAY_SIZE);

  cout << endl;


  return 0;
}

void selectionSort(int UnsortedArray[], int SizeofArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i< SizeofArray; i++)
    {
        int smallest = UnsortedArray[i];
        int smallestIndex = i;

        for(int m = i; m < SizeofArray; m++)
        {
            if(UnsortedArray[m] < smallest)
            {
                smallest = UnsortedArray[m];
                smallestIndex = m;
            }

        }
        swap(UnsortedArray[i], UnsortedArray[smallestIndex]);
    }

}
```

Sorry if i have a lot of mistake, im only a beginner.

Comment: provide in which line in a [mcve]?

Comment: Your function is expecting an array, but you send an int.

Comment: @Kyle Khalaf I tried adding finalArray[] but it didn't work

Comment: I think you meant to send `numbers` and not `finalArray`.  `finalArray = numbers[counter];` is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: at first you forgot the return value of `selectionSort` in the declaration. Then you send `finalArray` which is an `int`, not a `int[]` in the call to `selectionSort`. So replace it with `numbers` and it compiles

Comment: I think the "duplicated" link for closing is unrelated. Voted to re-open

Comment: @max i was sitting here for about an hour trying to figure out whats wrong and it took u guys like a minute or two